# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 3, file "Code.gs")

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a Google Sheet Script that sets a formula and autofills the formula for each new row added and getting the error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 3, file "Code.gs")

Here is the script:

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 ss.getRange("AE2").setFormula("=LEFT(F2,FIND("for $",F2)-1)");
 }
```

I can't figure out where the missing ) is? The formula works without any problems in the sheet itself

Honestly I am not experienced in writing scripts so any help will be appreciated

Comment: Color highlighting shows the issue. You have the nested quotes It sees `"=LEFT(F2,FIND("` and than it errors out

Comment: If you need to have literal double quotes, it's better to use single quoted strings: `ss.getRange("AE2").setFormula('=LEFT(F2,FIND("for $",F2)-1)');`

Comment: Thanks makes perfect sense and works! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can try escaping your " marks.

```
function myFunction() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   ss.getRange("AE2").setFormula("=LEFT(F2,FIND(\"for $\",F2)-1)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the inner quotation marks otherwise they break the string input for `setFormula` to early and cause the `SyntaxError`. You escape characters in the string with a backslash (`\`).

```js
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 ss.getRange("AE2").setFormula("=LEFT(F2,FIND(\"for $\",F2)-1)");
 }
```